# EditText focus issue in expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

In Expandable `ListView`, I have 4 `EditText` in each child item of a row, when I try top open keypad by touching anyone `EditText` in child items, `EditText` focus is not happening to the clicked/touched `EditText`. I used *`adjustPan`* for the activity in manifest. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you add some code to understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use adjustPan .Instead use adjustResize.**

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

**In xml file write below code in parent layout.**

```
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```